# Is there a way to cast values when using operator.itemgetter() as sort key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I've a list of lists containing string represented numbers:

```
nums = [['1','3'],['2','2'],['1','2'],['0','2'],['11','2']]
```

I need to sort these numerically ascending by the first then second entries without modify the string representation of the numbers in the original list.  Also, want to avoid creating another 2nd copy of the list with everything mapped to integers explicitly--imagine this is a huge list.

Both `sort()` and `sorted()` works nicely with tuples and lists, so with a lambda key, I can do the following:

```
>>> sorted(nums, key=lambda n: (int(n[0]),int(n[1])) 
[['0', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['2', '2'], ['11', '2']]
```

Happy days...

However, I've seen a number of postings about sorting being faster using the `operator.itemgetter()` as key function over using a lambda.  **Without getting into a discussion of the validity of these claims**, does anyone if it's possible apply a conversion from string to integer for comparision when using `operator.itemgetter()`:

The following obviously fails, due to the strings being compared as strings, not numbers:

```
>>> sorted(nums, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1)) 
[['0', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['11', '2'], ['2', '2']]
```

Comment: Yeeesssss.... but it would be much longer than the equivalent naive lambda.

Comment: `itemgetter` isn't very useful if you're getting *all* the items.

Comment: You called the list `nums` but it doesn't contain any numbers, just lists and strings. Unless sorting is the only time those strings' numerical value matters and they need to be strings at all other times, you could just cast them to integers in the original list, and then you wouldn't need to pass a sort key.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  Forgot to add that detail, good catch.  I cannot modify the existing list--they need to stay strings.  Just want them sorted as if they were integers.  Updating the question text to clarify this.

Comment: Lists containing strings representing numbers is a strange data to have.  Convert to numeric when/where the data comes into your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways, for example using [`iteration_utilities.chained`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/chained.html) <sup>1</sup> and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> import operator import itemgetter
>>> from iteration_utilities import chained
>>> from functools import partial

>>> itemgetter_int = chained(operator.itemgetter(0, 1), partial(map, int), tuple)
>>> sorted(nums, key=itemgetter_int)
[['0', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['2', '2'], ['11', '2']]
```

It works but it's definetly slower than using a `lambda` or custom defined function.

If you really need speed you could cythonize the `lambda`-function (or write it in C by hand) but if you just need it in one place just use a throw-away `lambda`. Especially if it's in `sorted` because it has `O(nlog(n))` comparisons so the `O(n)` function calls *probably* don't contribute much to the overall execution time.

---

<sup>1: This is a function in a [3rd party extension module](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that I authored. It needs to be seperatly installed, for example via `conda` or `pip`.</sup>

Comment: @Ray, you're running different code than he posted, then.  "iteration_utilities" is a 3rd-party extension:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iteration_utilities

Comment: @Ray this chained is just a function composition, if you want a no third-party version of that, you can do it like `from functools import partial, reduce;from operator import itemgetter` and use them as `itemgetter_int = partial(reduce, lambda x,f:f(x), [itemgetter(0,1), partial(map,int),tuple])`

Comment: @TimPeters you are indeed correct.  Installed iterations_utilities via pip it now works as expected.

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks for the built in only version.   The one thing I think I note is the call to the Lambda would require a non-C python function evaluation--correct?

Comment: @Ray yeah, pretty much

Comment: @Ray oh sorry, should have mentioned that it's a 3rd party extension. The `chained` is actually a C-function and even though `int`, `map`, `itemgetter`, `tuple` are also C functions it's slower than the `lambda n: (int(n[0]),int(n[1])`. I wouldn't have mentioned it (because it's slower) but you explicitly asked about avoiding `lambda`.

Comment: @Copperfield Well using a `reduce` with `lambda` to avoid the simpler `key=lambda...` kind of defeats the purpose, don't you think? :)

Comment: @MSeifert  no problem, wasn't concerned with performance, just if there was a way.  Your method does works and avoids calling non-C python functions.  That beings said, a custom c function is probably route needed and avoid using `itemgetter`.

Comment: @MSeifert indeed, but that wasn't my goal ;)

Comment: @Ray Cython make it easy to write C extentions if you are not familiar with C and/or don't want to go too far from python

Comment: Why not just `chained(partial(map, int), tuple)`? The itemgetter is a no-op.

Comment: @Eric that works as well `sorted(nums, key=chained(partial(map, int), list))`

Answer (score 4):

`operator.itemgetter` is fast not because it does something special in `sort`, but because it is entirely [written in c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Modules/_operator.c#L934-L1106), and does not involve calling a python function.

So what you're looking for is a *C function* that does what you want - `itemgetter` is a red herring.

In python 2, you can avoid calling pure-python functions with `key=functools.partial(map, int)`. This won't work in python 3, because `map` no longer returns a list or tuple. This also might not be any faster than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

And 4 years later here is the solution I think best fits the spirit of the question:

```
>>> import operator
>>> ig = operator.itemgetter(0,1)
>>> nums = [['1', '3'], ['2', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['0', '2'], ['11', '2']]
>>> sorted( nums,key = lambda x : tuple(map(int,ig(x))) )
[['0', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['2', '2'], ['11', '2']]
```